# defining EBS volume size to use with glusterfs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, glusterfs

I'm trying to build a glusterfs network file system on Amazon EC2.

I trying to define EBS Volume size. I'm planning to use 2 x 12Gb volumes at the begining stage and then add extra volumes in the future.

What size should be the new volumes? Should they be 12Gb too?  is larger volumes (lets say 100Gb ) allowed to attach to the glusterfs pool?

Kind regards...

Comment: You mean GB and not Gb here, right?

Answer (score 0):

Glusterfs is pretty forgiving about what kind of volume it'll present. The limit is more in the form of inodes than simple size. The largest volume I've heard of presented was in the petabyte range, though what combination of replicas & stripes I couldn't tell you.

Which is to say, this isn't something you need to worry about; you're not big enough yet.

Comment: I mean all the volumes should be the same size? If I started with 12Gb volume, the future volumes should be 12Gb?

Comment: @zontragon Replica-sets need to be identical, but additional members of stripe-sets can be heterogeneous in size.